# Fish shell input redirection from subshell output

Tags: shell, remote-access, wireshark, fish

When I want to run Wireshark locally to display a packet capture running on another machine, this works on bash, using input redirection from the output of a subshell:

`wireshark -k -i <(ssh user@machine "sudo dumpcap -P -w - -f '<filter>' -i eth0")`

From what I could find, the syntax for similar behavior on the fish shell is the same but when I run that command on fish, I get the Wireshark output on the terminal but can't see the Wireshark window.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fish equivalent of `<()` isn't well suited to this use case. Is there some reason you can't use this simpler and more portable formulation?

```
ssh user@machine "sudo dumpcap -P -w - -f '<filter>' -i eth0" | wireshark -k -i -
```

Comment: @grochmal 's answer didn't work for me, the behavior was still the same (Wireshark window did not display locally), maybe there's something else missing... This did it though, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

What you're using there in bash is [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (the `<()` syntax).  It is a **bash specific** syntax (although `zsh` adopted this same syntax along with its own `=()`).

[`fish` does have process substitution](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9017996) under a different syntax (`(process | psub)`). For example:

```
wireshark -k -i (ssh user@machine "sudo dumpcap -P -w - -f '<filter>' -i eth0" | psub)
```

---

```
bash        | equivalent in fish
----------- | ------------------
cat <(ls)   | cat (ls|psub)
ls > >(cat) | N/A (need to find a way to use a pipe, e.g. ls|cat)
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#psub), there's no fish equivalent to `>(ls)`

Comment: @glennjackman - Correct, thanks, and i was confident that i tested it.  `(psub|cat)` does not fail, but it gives the temporary FIFO name not a stream.